# 22.04 Unresponsive mouse-click boundary outside Firefox window borders

Tags: gnome, firefox, 22.04, snap, focus

On a freshly installed laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (5.15.0-46-generic) and Gnome, I notice a strange behaviour with Firefox (103.0.2).

When it overlaps other windows there's a hidden boundary around the window border, where the mouse is unresponsive if you click the underlying window to bring it in focus and on top. Only when moving further away from the edge of Firefox window does the mouse click work as expected (at least about half a centimeter on my monitors, both main and external).

[image: Screenshot showing the area that is unresponsive.]

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be an issue specific to Firefox, probably on Wayland only (Firefox is a snap running on xwayland). Does not happen with Thunderbird installed as a snap (and also xwayland).

Comment: Do you think it is related to the snap bundled Firefox specifically? I am thinking of re-installing Firefox from apt with [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) as my guide. I have some other issues with the snap install anyway.

Comment: Go ahead, then you can see whether the regular Firefox also exhibits this issue or not. Will run natively in Wayland, so also that can make a difference versus running in xwayland.

Comment: Same problem here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426469/firefox-windows-capture-clicks-on-an-area-larger-than-its-real-size-on-ubuntu-22

Comment: I confirm that this only happens when running on Wayland. If in the login screen I select "Ubuntu on Xorg" then there is no issue.

Comment: Firefox bug tracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1781262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution would be to restore the browser title bar.

Right click near a tab > Customize toolbar > Check "title bar" at the bottom left of the screen.

Clicking behind even near the firefox boundaries should work again then.

Comment: Marvellous, thank you. How unintuitive can you make such 'feature' (??) in the UI?

Comment: The 'hidden title bar mode' by default must be a problem for the calculation of the edge positions I guess, I had the same issue and solved it by chance

Comment: This works for me too as a workaround, but I really don't want the Title Bar...

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by enabling Wayland support for Firefox.

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add a new line below `PATH` with:

```
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
```

Save and restart or logout.

You can check if it worked on `about:support`. Search for `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND`.

Source: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/09/enable-wayland-firefox-chrome/