# Firefox windows capture clicks on an area larger than its real size on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, 22.04, wayland, titlebar, focus

It looks as if Firefox windows are capturing the mouse clicks on an area larger than their window.  The extra area expands to approximately the size of the titlebar on the 4 directions (top, bottom, left, right).

For example, if I click close to a Firefox window which is not focused, it gets the focus.  Or if a Firefox window is overlapping another window, I cannot focus this other window by clicking in the area which is near the overlapping Firefox window.

For example, in this screenshot, the Firefox window which is overlapped cannot be clicked:

[image]

If I click and drag then it works, the overlapped window is focused and moved to the top.

This started happening after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I can confirm this (surprising) behaviour. An underlying window does not get the focus unless clicked more than roughly 20 pixels outside the Firefox window. It happens at all four edges. This sounds like a bug, in which case developers will want to know: how did you install Firefox? Mine comes from a snap package (`1:1snap1-0ubuntu2`).

Comment: Also snap here, it was installed via deb on 20.04 but the upgrade to 22.04 moves it to snap.

Comment: I have noticed that this only happens when running Ubuntu on Wayland.  If in the login screen I select "Ubuntu on Xorg" then there is no issue.  I have added the tag "wayland" to the question.

Comment: This is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1438255/1625817